# is this the only way to Update database by CellEndEdit in datagridview?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

After working with datagridview for days, maybe weeks I'm starting to really learn by myself and from the people here, and I thank you all, but I also start to get confused at the same time. My question is, is there any other way to update `MySQL Database` at `CellEndEdit` aside from this code?

```
  Me.Validate()
  Me.OutgoingdeliveriesBindingSource.EndEdit()
  Me.OutgoingdeliveriesTableAdapter.Update(Me.OutgoingDeliveriesDataSet1.outgoingdeliveries)
```

Any advice or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one that I use which could be modified to use in your instance. This actually seems to work rather well in my use of it.

```
Private Sub FinancialBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles FinancialBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
  FinancialDataGridView.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
  db.SaveChanges()
End Sub
```